# Kibana Max Attempted Reached while exporting CVS file

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat

In the "Discover" section, as we would like to export the result in a csv file,
The result is around 1 Million documents, when we try to export in csv, it never works...
produces error: Max attempts reached (3), But when tried to export small document around 50K it works fine and created the report successfully.

This is what my configuration looks in **kibana.yml**

```
## x-pack module setting
xpack.reporting.queue.timeout: 3600000
xpack.reporting.csv.maxSizeBytes: 1024000000
xpack.reporting.csv.scroll.size: 10000

server.maxPayloadBytes: 1073741824
```

and this is the congiuguration in **elasticseaerch.yml**

```
http.compression: true
http.max_content_length: 1024mb
```

Didn't understand what causing the issue.

Comment: Do you have some Kibana and/or ES logs you can share?

Comment: do you want any specific grep search logs?,  because the logs are too long..

Comment: Well, obviously, the logs from around the time you're attempting the export

Comment: Any updates about those logs?

Comment: Have you got any resolution?